# Azure DevOps contains yaml express not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I've got the sample yaml pipeline here:

```
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
- test-expressions

variables:
  folder: application1
  applications: application1,application2,application3
  exclude: application2

steps:
- ${{ if ne('$(folder)', '') }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Output the folder - $(folder)`n";
      Write-Host "Output the applications - $(applications)";
    displayName: folder is not blank

- ${{ if contains('$(applications)', '$(folder)') }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Output the folder - $(folder)"
    displayName: applications contains folder

- ${{ if contains('$(folder)', '$(applications)') }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Output the folder - $(folder)"
    displayName: folder contains applications
```

[image: pipeline yaml]

the first task is enabled as expected. However, I was expecting the second task to also be enabled when the pipeline runs.  However, it is doesn't run. Can anyone see what the problem is?  Either I am incorrectly using the contains syntax, or it is not behaving as expected

Just for background, I would prefer to use the if statements in yaml rather than conditions because I find it better from a usability perspective. I don't want to display any skipped tasks in the pipeline if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this syntax: `variables['applications']` and not: `'$(applications)'`.

So it will be:

```
- ${{ if contains(variables['applications'], variables['folder']) }}:
```